# Converting/Saving XML as CSV using Open XML SDK in SSIS Script Task

Tags: excel, csv, ssis, openxml-sdk

Can help me with below query please? I wrote the below C# code in SSIS script task to convert my web downloaded XML spreadsheet 2003 to CSV format. This code works absolutely fine on my local machine because my local machine has Office installed on it so Excel Reference/assemblies are available.

However, server machine doesn't have office installed on it (And there is a reason for that). So below code doesn't work on it. I have read few forums where people suggested to Install "Open XM SDK for Office" on server machine so managed to do that. Now how to convert XML to csv using XML SDKs. Below is my code from my Local machine using Office assemblies

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
#endregion
public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here

        Excel.Application excelapp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook Datasource = 
(Excel.Workbook)excelapp.Workbooks.Add(1);

        var DownloadPath = 
 Dts.Variables["User::varDownloadPathNew"].Value.ToString();
        var ConvertedPath = 
 Dts.Variables["User::varConvertedFileName"].Value.ToString();

        string FileName = DownloadPath;
        var format = Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV;

        Datasource = excelapp.Workbooks.Open(FileName, Missing.Value, 
  Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, 
  Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, 
  Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

        Datasource.SaveAs(ConvertedPath, format, Missing.Value, 
  Missing.Value, false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
        Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlUserResolution, true,
        Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

        //Clean
        Datasource.Close(true);


  System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(Datasource);

        excelapp.Quit();

   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelapp);

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

Comment: If the XML spreadsheet is not a XLSX file (a zip packag of XML files) then the Open XML SDK cannot help you. The XML file format of Excel 2003 was *not* XLSX; these files were simple XML files, not zip packages. So you should be able to use standard XML tools to read/convert them.

Comment: @CindyMeister Many thanks for you reply, I have tried using all Standard xml readers/Editors and Editors are throwing error message as there some characters in downloaded source file not liked by Source Editors. I can download the file as .xls or xlsx. Any idea how can i convert it to csv then using sdk ?

Comment: The first thing you'd need to do is inspect the xlsx file "package" using the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool. That will tell you in what XML files in the package the information you need is stored. It will also give you an idea about what SDK objects can be used to address that information. What you ask is not a simple, straight-forward task. Actually, the Excel 2003 XML would be much simpler to convert (you could probably use an xslt) - and I'm surprised a standard editor can't open such a file. I never had any issues of that kind 15 years ago when I looked at those kinds of files...